# How to reshape each row of a Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, image, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe where each row corresponds to 1024 pixel values of an image. I want to reshape each row to a 32x32 image. The shape of my dataframe is (32495, 1024).

I tried:

```
features.iloc[0].values.reshape(32, 32)
```

However, this only works for a single row. Doing this for the whole dataframe like so:

```
features.values.reshape(32, 32)
```

results in the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 33274880 into shape (32,32)
```

Any ideas on how to go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and revise your question accordingly

Comment: Added the numpy tag since you actually needed to have them as numpy array at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the number of rows you have to reshape like the following:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((32495,1024)))
my_df.shape
>> (32495, 1024)

reshaped_array = my_df.values.reshape(32495, 32, 32)
reshaped_array.shape
>> (32495, 32, 32)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get for instance numpy array from your DataFrame, but the problem is you cannot feed DataFrame with rank 3 numpy array.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 9))
arr = df.values
arr = np.reshape(arr, (10, 3, 3))
```

This step will fail:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
```

The other answer provided numpy array, at the end, not the DataFrame.

Comment: Actually, I forgot to specify this in the question but I did indeed require a numpy array from the DataFrame. Sorry about that. Thanking your for the taking the time to answer though!

Comment: Sure, no problem, numpy arrays seams like perfect for this, even you can  to convert them to tensors in TensorFlow. I will add numpy tag then.