# Collapse rows of dataframe into matricies

Tags: python, pandas, image, csv

I have a csv that produces a 60000 x 785 dataframe. Each row has a number as the first column and the rest of the 784 columns are pixel values for that number. I need to collapse the 784 pixels into 28 x 28 matrices. The resulting dataframe will have the digit in the first column and the second column will be the 28x28 matrix of pixel values.

`digit p1 p2 p3 p4 ... p785`

I've tried reshaping the data but that failed, so what should I do to reshape it?

Answer (score 0):

first set 'digit' to index, then try this:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.values.reshape(28, -1), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to store the data as a dictionary with keys are digits in the 1st column and values are arrays of size 28x28 containing pixel values of each row.

- Import packages:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

- Create a test.csv file:

```
with open('./test.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for i in range(60000):
        row_i = (i+1)*np.ones(785, dtype=int)
        writer.writerow(row_i)
f.close
```

- Load the csv as a dataframe:

```
data = pd.read_csv('./test.csv', header=None, index_col=0)
data = data.T.to_dict('list')
for i, value in data.items():
    data[i] = np.asarray(value).reshape(28,28)
```

- Check the output

```
print(len(data))
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a dataframe of shape 6000 rows and 785 columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(…)
df.shape
# (6000, 785)
```

Extract the digit column for later use:

```
digits = df['digit']
```

Reshape the other column values to (6000, 28, 28):

```
arr = df.iloc[1:].values.reshape(6000, 28, 28)
# -> np.array
```

Put the components back together:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'digit': digits,
                   # dataframe like only 1-d things
                   'matrix': list(arr)
                  })
```

---

…by the way, your question is strongly related to [How to reshape each row of a Dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55994134/how-to-reshape-each-row-of-a-dataframeu)